# Why the ROS client could fail!

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have implemented a new server and client. The server can work very well but the client always failed!! The errors are shown below:

The srv file is as follows:

```
float32 cpg1
float32 cpg2
float32 cpg3
float32 cpg4
---
float32 input1
float32 input2
float32 input3
float32 input4
```

### And the crucial part of the client is:

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "Cpgvalue");

ros::NodeHandle node;
ros::ServiceClient crawling = node.serviceClient<Crawlers::Cpg>("Cpgdata");
Crawlers::Cpg crawlingdata;
std::vector<float> res;
res.resize(4);
ros::Rate loop_rate(1000);

while(ros::ok())
{
crawlingcpg.CpgNetworkCalculation(feedback);
crawlingdata.request.cpg1 = crawlingcpg.CpgResult[0];
crawlingdata.request.cpg2 = crawlingcpg.CpgResult[1];
crawlingdata.request.cpg3 = crawlingcpg.CpgResult[2];
crawlingdata.request.cpg4 = crawlingcpg.CpgResult[3];

    res[0] = crawlingdata.response.input1;
    res[1] = crawlingdata.response.input2;
    res[2] = crawlingdata.response.input3;
    res[3] = crawlingdata.response.input4;

loop_rate.sleep();

ROS_INFO("Cpg1:[%f]", crawlingcpg.CpgResult[0]); ROS_INFO("Cpg2:[%f]", crawlingcpg.CpgResult[1]);   
if (crawling.call(crawlingdata))
    {      
      ROS_INFO("suceeded!");
    }
    else{
      ROS_INFO("client failed" );
      return 1;     
    }

    ros::spin();
}
return 0;
```

Whatever I modified, I always got the same error:

```
[ INFO] [1314708828.730975843]: client failed
```

Can somebody figure out what is the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11043/why-the-ros-client-could-fail!/) by [Gauss Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/815/gauss-lee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your service callback needs to have the line

```
return true;
```

at the end. If it returns `false`, the service call is considered as failed. If you don't return anything, I believe the behavior is undefined. You actually should get a compiler warning that the function doesn't return a value.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gauss Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/815/gauss-lee/) on 2011-08-30**:
Yes. Thank you! I suddenly find All my clients cannot work anymore. The roscore is warning it cannot write into the  ROS_LOG_DIR, it needs reset! I do not know why? I just updated my ROS sometimes when it needs me to.

**Comment by [Gauss Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/815/gauss-lee/) on 2011-08-30**:
Yes. Thank you! I suddenly find All my clients cannot work anymore. The roscore is warning it cannot write into the  ROS_LOG_DIR, it needs reset! I do not know why? I just updated my ROS sometimes when it needs me to.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't see an obvious problem in the client code, given that the server is up an running, when you execute the code. Can you also give the server code for comparison and/or test with the rosservice tool manually?

The one thing that is wrong (but wouldn't change the error message) is that you read in the result before you call the service. That can only work after the service call, i.e. in the "succeeded" branch.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-08-30**:
rosservice is documented at http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosservice

**Comment by [Gauss Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/815/gauss-lee/) on 2011-08-30**:
Thank you for your reply. I do not know how to test with ROSSERVICE TOOL. Could you give me a simple example?